# How to edit bootable UDF iso file on Linux

Tags: linux, iso-image, bootable-media, udf

I'm looking for a way to edit an UDF bootable iso file on Linux so has to keep it bootable.

Can you help ?

Comment: You should post this question on the Software Recommendations SE site. Software requests are off-topic on SuperUser.

Comment: @music2myear Hi, I have just edited my question. Is it OK ?

Comment: Yes, that looks like it avoids the software request issue.

Comment: @music2myear Can you therefore please remove the "on hold" status of my question ?

Comment: SU is community-moderated. Most actions require 5 concurring votes, including closing and reopening questions. You can track the progress in links under your question. If you want the immediate attention of a Moderator, please check out the chat options listed in the sidebar.